# How to make the flexible space discrete?

Tags: lengths, cjk

When typesetting Eastern Asian materials, positions of characters are normally relatively rigid. But there are unavoidable situations in which flexible spaces are needed, which are typically defined by glue.

Now the question is to force the length of glue to be discrete but not continuous (e.g., forcing it to be only integral multiplies of a specific length) in order to ensure the positions of CJK characters being still regular.

Thank you for your attention.

Comment: classic tex (and xetex) can not do that in any reasonable way. with luatex you may be able to do something by iterating over the node list in a post linebreak callback.